# How to write text containing $var to a bash file?

Tags: shell-script, files, write

I am having trouble with writing `case $1 in` a bash file. I tried with

```
cat <<EOT > /etc/init.d/startup.sh
#!/bin/bash

PATH=/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin

case "$1" in
    start)
        bash /root/install.sh >> /root/installation_log.txt 2>&1
        ;;
    stop|restart|reload)
        ;;
esac
EOT
```

But the problem is it writes everything to `startup.sh` but `$1`. Line

```
case "$1" in
```

become

```
case "" in
```

after the operation.
What to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quote the `EOF` terminator passed to the `<<` operator (in any way):

```
cat << 'EOT' > file
$var
EOT
```

Or

```
cat << \EOT
cat << EO\T
cat << "E"'O'T
cat << ""EOT
```

That's the [documented and standard way](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_07_04) to prevent any type of expansion inside the here-document.

Comment: Wow! Awesome. Could you please add some reference?

Comment: @haccks, see edit with link to the POSIX shell specification.

Answer (score 1):

Change the first `EOT` into `'EOT'` to prevent variable expansion

eg

```
cat <<'EOT' > /etc/init.d/startup.sh
```